# A girl and boy go back in time to stop their siblings from getting married

Tags: story-identification, manga

In this manga, a girl and boy go back in time to stop their siblings from getting married. I forgot the details about this manga. I just need the name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is *"[Goodbye, In-Law!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/goodbye-in-law/reviews)"* (AKA *再也不见 / 굿바이 사돈*)

> The story begins with Da-ae and Han-eol, our two main characters that have hated each other following a misunderstanding in high school several years back. When they meet again as adults, they realize they are going to be in-laws through the marriage of their older siblings. However, after the tragic death of their newlywed siblings, the two also get in an accident where they are transported eight years into the past. The two, initially flabbergasted by the incident, quickly come to the conclusion that this must be a chance to fix their future since this was the time that their older siblings first met. Although sworn enemies, the two must put aside their differences and figure out how to change the future to avoid their siblings' death.
>
> [image: Title and cover image for "Goodbye, In-Law". A girl with pink-black hair and a boy with black hair look at each other while holding a book together.]